# Excel Cell showing the formula text instead of its value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm referring the A10 cell value in an excel file say "D:/Sample.xlsx" from another excel file using the formula "='C:[Test.xlsx]Sheet1'!B10". It works fine and gives me a value say 10 in A10 of "D:/Sample.xlsx" excel file. In the same way when I try to input "C:/" path in C10 of the "D:/Sample.xlsx" file and tried "=CONCATENATE("=", "'",C10,"[Test.xlsx]Sheet1'!B10")" formula in A10, instead of showing the value of the formula (10), it is just showing the text. Can anyone help me with the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your CONCATENATE formula is building a text string, not putting a formula into the cell. You will likely need VBA in order to construct your formula string and insert it into the cell.

Comment: Have a look at the "Indirect" formula, it will do what you want.

Comment: for example ... `Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(1, 1).Formula = "=TODAY()"`

Comment: Hello Dan and Oldguy, Thanks for your replies. My other excel file will not be opened to use the function Indirect. Even if I open the other sheet and use Indirect function, I'm just getting the value "#REF!" in the cell. Can you please suggest any other approach?

Comment: Hi OldGuy, Can you please provide any VB macro if you have. I'm new to VB programming. Thank you

Comment: I checked that as a first step Brak, but it in General Mode not as Text mode.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [indirect](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) function.

> Returns the reference specified by a text string. References are immediately evaluated to display their contents

Note that the other file has to be open.

Comment: Hello Rene, Thanks for your reply. My other excel file will not be opened to use the function Indirect. Even if I open the other sheet and use Indirect function, I'm just getting the value "#REF!" in the cell. Can you please suggest any other approach?